# docker run can't find software parameter

Tags: docker

I used the below command but for some reasons, it can't find the parameter.

```
$ ls lachesis.ini 
lachesis.ini
$ docker run -it 5071f1ab27a0 /usr/local/bin/Lachesis lachesis.ini
RunParams is parsing INI file at lachesis.ini
ERROR: Can't find file lachesis.ini
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: At a guess, I'd say you forgot to copy the file into the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a container runs, it runs it's own sandbox with it's own filesystem. In your example, the lachesis.ini is on your system outside of the container. You can mount locations inside of the container using the `-v` option for docker. Using your example, you might try something like this:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/tmpdir -it 5071f1ab27a0 /usr/local/bin/Lachesis /tmpdir/lachesis.ini
```

This will mount your the current directory of your shell to `/tmpdir` inside of the container.